# finding the angle of a triangle using tan

Tags: java, lwjgl, trigonometry

alright so im making a ai for a zombie in one of my games, but when i try to rotate the zombie so that he is facing the player everything goes out of wack. they rotate the wrong way, spin around when i get close even though the angle shouldn't change.
here is some of my code: ps ignore the z, this game is 3d but im only rotating on on axis so i can code this as though it was xy.

```
//get camera/player yx
float PlayerYPosition = Player.getPosition().y;
float PlayerXPosition = Player.getPosition().z;
//get zombie yx
float ZombieYPosition = Zombie.getPosition().y;
float ZombieXPosition = Zombie.getPosition().z;
//get side lengths
float sideY = (CameraYPosition - ZombieYPosition);
float sideX = (CameraXPosition - ZombieXPosition);
//get angle
float angle = (float)Math.atan2(sideX,sideY);
//move decimal place out so ex: 0.90f is 90.0f
float ans = angle * 100;
//set rotation of zombie
super.setRotY(ans);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Math.atan2`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#atan2(double,%20double)) returns its value in [radians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian), not degrees. To convert to degrees, multiply by either 180/pi or 360/(2 pi):

```
float ans = angle * 180 / Math.PI;
```

Java even has a builtin function for this, [`Math.toDegrees`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#toDegrees(double)): (thanks @yshavit)

```
float ans = Math.toDegrees(angle);
```

Also, what @yshavit says in the comments: you should be using radians throughout the code. But that's perhaps too much work, or you might rely on 3rd party libraries which work with degrees.

Comment: A better option, if you can, is to have `super.RotY(ans)` (and whatever it uses) also be in radians. That way everything's consistent, and you don't have to keep wondering "wait, is this `float` a degree or radian?" every time you see it.

Comment: so i want to convert it to degrees by using float ans = angle * 360/(2 pi);

Comment: Also, rather than doing the math yourself, why not use [`Math.toDegrees`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#toDegrees(double))? That gives a nice, easy-to-understand name to the operation.